# Using MPI_Put with shared memory windows

Tags: mpi, hpc

I have created a shared memory window to communicate with intra node neighbors.

```
MPI_Win_allocate_shared(2*size*sizeof(double), 1, MPI_INFO_NULL, 
                        shmcomm, &mem, &win);
double *anew=mem; 
double *aold=mem+size;
```

and I would to use MPI RMA when a neighbor is within an inter-node location, so ideally I would like to do something like

```
MPI_Put(&aold[index], 1, Xtype, left, offset, 1, Xtype, win);
```

However this reports an error since `win` has been allocated in the shared memory environment so it does not understand neighbors outside its own node. 
Is there a way to create a secondary window to be used with `aold` so I can do something like

```
MPI_Put(&aold[index], 1, Xtype, left, offset, 1, Xtype, OtherWin);
```

Comment: Hi Did you try this ? I am curious if it is possible. As I see one can bind this aold to a new window. I do not have resources to test it thought.

Comment: @AdityaG I got it working, I'll post a solution soon

Comment: Perfect. That will be helpful. Thank you.